# ASIHTTPRequest retrieve server certificate

Tags: ssl, asihttprequest

For some legacy and internal reasons, I need to retrieve the certificate of the server (and ones from the chain as well), and read its fingerprint.

I understand this is easy to implement using AFNetworking or NSURLConnection since I only need to implement it in

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

But is it possible to do the same thing when using ASIHTTPRequest, which is just just basically a wrapper of CFNetworking?

Once again, I don't have a client certificate and my goal is to get the certificate from the server to read its fingerprint of issuer.

I will need to validate the fingerprint of server certificate in client and continue the request if it matches the one I expected, or cancel the request / throw error otherwise. Is this possible using ASIHTTPRequest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I verified that there's no way to do this using CFNetworking (what ASIHTTPRequest is using), see https://devforums.apple.com/thread/87346. For those who don't have ios Developers account (I am not sure why you are reading this though), "No. After thinking about this in depth I don't think it's possible. NSURLConnection, which does this, use a private hook into CFHTTPStream, and you won't be able to use that."

Btw, we rewrote our network layer using NSURLConnection and solved this problem

Comment: but I read the source code of ASIHttpRequest,seems like already have ssl pinning feature in line 1211 of ASIHttpRequest.m

Comment: @Forrest it's not SSL pinning. It's just validate that the certificate is a signed & valid certificate. Hackers could potentially get a signed, valid certificate from a bad OA claiming you own the website. SSL pinning actually compare the details of the certificate to see whether it's signature matches what you know. If you are building a one server app, SSL pinning is definitely the thing to do

Comment: Thanks. I understand why need SSL Pinning against such MIMA. So it is easy to implement SSL Pinning for ASI if the server's certificate can be got, then just verify if this cert is in the trusted pool. But the thing is how to get the live request's certificate ? NSNURConnection provide that delegate API, but ASI is not based on it, that means we cann't get , right ?

Comment: @Forrest exactly. CFNetworking didn't provide the API